# How to save and load content from html WYSIWYG editor in angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I think I will end up using a node/express backend with MongoDB if that makes sense for this situation...

I eventually want to be able to save the content from the content editable div to backend in a way that it can be reuploaded at a later time from the backend... the reuploaded data then can be placed in a non-editable HTML div for display, or back into a content editable div for more editing.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Maybe there is a way to save all of the dom elements from within the editor div, in a way that can be translated back into HTML so it renders?

Thanks, any advice is appreciated

HTML

```
  <div>
    <input type="button" (click)="iBold()" value="B">
  </div>
  <div id='editor' contenteditable>
    <h1>A WYSIWYG Editor.</h1>
    <p>Try making some changes here. Add your own text.</p>
  </div>
```

Angular Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  model = '<h1>A WYSIWYG Editor.</h1><p>Try making some changes here.     Add your own text.</p>';

  editor: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editor = document.getElementById('editor');
  }
  iBold() {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add a 2nd answer because possibly I misunderstood the question with the first answer. If you are talking about the content of a single div then you could do checks to ensure the contents are valid using `jQuery.parseHtml()`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

For a step up for extra umph you could use jsdom, which allows you to create a DOM from a string:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

Which you can traverse like you would traverse the Windows DOM, etc.

Also worth looking at cheerio:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

All these libs can be used client and server side.

They can be used to check validity, check contents, check for disallowed tags, etc

In Angular you would render HTML that is known to be valid like so:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHTML"></div>
```

See https://www.dev6.com/Angular-2-HTML-binding

You would possibly want it to work something like this:

**DIV ONE** - renders the HTML as plain text (during editing only)

**DIV TWO** - renders the parsed HTML if it is valid, both during and after editing (should always be valid when editing is finished, attempting to close an editing session should test validity using the aforementioned libs)

But consider the security concerns at:

https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis

Comment: I'm going to put more time into reading this tomorrow after my exam. Thank you so much for the help... I am excited about this side project

Comment: I will likely also reach out if I have a question / thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Node/express and Mongo sounds like a great idea.

Returning HTML / DOM stuff, this sounds like a bad idea. Keep the frontend logic at the frontend.

In the old days frontend logic and backend logic was always thrown together, e.g. PHP and Java.

Nowadays, there is a separation between the frontend and the backend for good reason.

This approach allows a single backend to serve potentially many different frontends and if the backend is returning JSON the frontends can render that JSON however they wish.

If you start returning HTML from the backend and a different frontend wants to render that data in a different way you are stuffed.

If you want to serve the data over a public API you are also stuffed.

Just keep it simple and return JSON from the backend.

We have this exact problem on the project I am working on and it is a real headache when it should be so simple.

Comment: okay so the issues with passing the inner html of the elements is because of security issues IF using a public api? my issue would be translating html to jsons because translating from html to json seems, weird... and then translating BACk to html. instead can just rest api grab the innerhtml as a string and sanitize it with a pipe and render

Comment: for security concerns in parsing HTML see https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis

Comment: ok, well if you take your approach you are likely to tie your backend to a single frontend - I understand the benefits of the approach you are advocating but it is not a practice that industry follows for reasons outlined - and you may face a lot of unnecessary and complicated challenges in managing edits, etc - not to mention there are probably very few libraries that would try and support such an approach - you may also lose some of the power of angular ... I mean if you try and sanitize <div *ngFor="let something of somethings"> how will it handle it? you may be constrained to static HTML

Comment: I very much doubt there is a lib intelligent enough to do the conversion from Angular HTML to static HTML and even more so, how would it convert it back again? if you are happy with static HTML then possibly it would work but I'm not convinced